# Scrape data over login with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, urlfetch

I would like to be able to scrape some data on a website with login. I use this to get login cookie :

```
var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
     "payload":{"login[email]" : email,
                "login[password]" : password
               }
   };

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(adresse,options);
   var sessionDetails = response.getAllHeaders();       
   Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

But I always have error (I try different things but always the same error..) here the log:

```
 Infos  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be nice if someone could help! I found some post where people say: I m able to login but... and when I try the code they give its not working!

Thanks!

Comment: did you try just using a curl request? something like `curl https://www.website.com/login -X POST` try this website to send it https://reqbin.com/curl

Comment: I dont know how to do... How can I use curl inside my spreadsheet with login information? Also how do I get the data I need, using xpath or something?

Comment: what i was getting at was, Do you even need a script for this? if you go to the link, type `curl *url here* -X POST` it should give you the post source code along with headers

Comment: you could also try something like `curl --include \
     --request POST \
'https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/oauth/token?client_id=&client_secret=&code='`

Comment: Not sure to understand, I dont have any API to get content. I try to extract data on yonomi account (last date/time a routine run). There is no way to communicate data from their dashboard so I try to pull data few times each minutes (it s location data so I need to refresh it often to get informed on time...) So the way I was looking for is with google sheet but it always have limitations since I havent api key ...

Comment: could you get an api key?

Comment: My last post ,  `curl --include \      --request POST \ '*your url here*'` was for your actual code, its a way of sending curl with JavaScript, so you can incorporate it in your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is code you can add to your current code for curl, I added it into an answer because it has better formatting

```js
curl --include \
     --request POST \ 
'***your url here***'
```

Comment: Google scripts seems not to recognize it! It tells me: unexpected identifier

Comment: just found out google app scripts doesn't support curl... maybe just write it in a node.js app and host it somewhere